# python numpy: row vector transpose

Tags: python, numpy, backpropagation

Suppose I have a 2-by-2 matrix `w = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` and an array `x = np.array([5, 6])`. If I run `y = np.dot(w, x)`, then y is another array `np.array([17, 39])`. All good here, although in fact we know `x` is treated as a column vector in the calculation, and the output `y` should also be a column vector.

During backpropagation, the gradient of `w` is `grad @ x.T`, where `@` is matrix multiplication, `x.T` is transpose of `x`, and `grad` is an array that is has same shape with y but filled with 1's: `grad = np.ones_like(y)`.

Ideally, `grad` should be a 2-by-1 vector, and `x.T` is 1-by-2 row vector, so the result is a 2-by-2 matrix, same dimension as w. However, both `grad` and `x` are 1-D arrays so the result becomes a single number.

Are there any solutions? Thanks for any help!

Comment: In `numpy` terms `x` is a 1d array.  It is not a "column vector".  `np.dot` clearly defines what it does when an argument is 1d.  `x.T` reverses the (one) dimension(s) of `x`; it does not add a dimension.  Curious, why do you use `np.dot` in one, and `@` in the other?

Comment: My mistakes. But they all produce the same result in this case. whether i use @, dot, or matmul

Comment: Any ways, if `x` is indeed (2,1), then `x.T` will be (1,2), and the last calculation will produce a (2,2).  A (2,1)@ with a (1,2) is also an 'outer' product, or broadcasted elementwise, since it's only a size 1 dimension that's added.

Comment: Usually ML questions data arrays are 2d (n-samples, n-features).  So even if there just one feature the array will be (n,1).  Shape (n,) is common in numpy, and for broadcasting acts as (1,n), but reshaping to (n,1) is also easy and used as needed.